# Get top column base on maximum other column using group by?

Tags: sql-server

How to get top column base on maximum other column using group by?

My raw data:

```
DECLARE @TB TABLE (ID INT, APP VARCHAR(25), PRICE MONEY)
INSERT INTO @TB
VALUES
(1, 'Apple', 10),
(1, 'Banana', 30),
(1, 'Orange', 20),
(2, 'Apple', 20),
(2, 'Banana', 30),
(2, 'Orange', 40)
```

[image]

This what I want:

[image]

Explain:

TOP_APP = Banana because MAX(PRICE) GROUP BY ID,

TOTAL = 60 because SUM(PRICE) GROUP BY ID.

Comment: Could you please share us your **current result** and **Expected result**?

Comment: I already share all above.

Comment: How come your total for Orange is 90 and for Banana is 50?

Comment: yes, SUM all price group by ID

Comment: You need to explain more detail. Because We can not reproduce your problem with your sample data along with Expected result.

Comment: Sorry, Orange is 90, Banana is 60, I will edit it,

Comment: Sorry for wrong question, please help me, read it again, I already edited it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ROW_NUMBER and aggregation to achieve your required output-

[DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bfe3393c7aac310c00d91a8657bbaf56)

```
SELECT A.ID,A.App,A.SUM 
FROM
(
    select *,
    SUM(Price) OVER(PARTITION BY ID) SUM,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Price DESC) RN
    from @tb
)A
WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: Sorry for wrong question, please help me, read it again, I already edited it

Answer (score 1):

[Demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9746b2bf242d3e37959e62c4aad61215)

```
;WITH cte_TempTable as 
(
  SELECT Id, app, price,
                SUM(Price) OVER(PARTITION BY ID) Total,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Price DESC) Row_Number
   FROM @TB
)

SELECT Id, app as TOP_APP, Total 
FROM cte_TempTable
WHERE Row_Number = 1
```

**Output**

```
Id  TOP_APP Total
1   Banana  60.0000
2   Orange  90.0000
```

Answer (score 0):

> As my assumption you want the result is

```
SELECT identity (int,1,1) as ID,
    APP AS TOP_APP
    ,SUM(PRICE) AS TOTAL INTO #T
FROM @TB
GROUP BY APP
order by SUM(PRICE)

select * from #t
```

Comment: Sorry for wrong question, please help me, read it again, I already edited it.